# Parse an hungarian date with readr::parse_date

Tags: r, date, parsing, locale, readr

I'm not able to parse very simple hungarian dates with `readr::parse_date`

```
parse_date('július 6.', format = '%B %e.', locale = locale('hu'))
```

even if the month is listed in the locale

```
> locale('hu')
<locale>
Numbers:  123,456.78
Formats:  %AD / %AT
Timezone: UTC
Encoding: UTF-8
<date_names>
Days:   vasárnap (V), hétfő (H), kedd (K), szerda (Sze), csütörtök (Cs), péntek (P), szombat (Szo)
Months: január (jan.), február (febr.), március (márc.), április (ápr.), május (máj.), június (jún.), július (júl.), augusztus
        (aug.), szeptember (szept.), október (okt.), november (nov.), december (dec.)
AM/PM:  de./du.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a year to the date and specify the encoding.

```
readr::parse_date("1 július 2000", "%d %B %Y",
           locale = locale(date_names = "hu", encoding = "latin1"))
```

Comment: uhm your code gives me NA again! I simply copy pasted it with no changes

Comment: For me, it returns:
[1] "2000-07-01"

Comment: uhm... some os setting problem? gotta post an issue I'm afraid

Comment: Strange. I tried even with your example, and the following code works fine for me:
parse_date('2000 július 6.', format = '%Y %B %d.', locale = locale(date_names = "hu", encoding = "latin1"))
[1] "2000-07-06"